# Event Sourcing in Microservices Using Spring Cloud and Reactor

Tags: docker, spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices, reactor

I am currently doing a research on building Microservices using spring boot and Docker. Luckily I found this blog 
[Event Sourcing in Microservices Using Spring Cloud and Reactor](http://www.kennybastani.com/2016/04/event-sourcing-microservices-spring-cloud.html) by Kenny Bastani. You can find the github project source code [here](https://github.com/kbastani/spring-cloud-event-sourcing-example).

I really want to up and run this example because it has the functionalities/technologies that I was looking for.

I am running Ubuntu desktop 16.04 OS and already installed the following software mentioned on the said blog.

- Maven 3
- Java 8
- Docker, Docker Machine
- Docker Compose

Then executed the following scripts. This is also based on the blog. I just reduced the virtualbox-memory & virtualbox-disk-size to avoid computer freeze.

1. $ docker-machine create event-source-demo --driver virtualbox
   --virtualbox-memory "1000" --virtualbox-disk-size "20000"
2. $ eval "$(docker-machine env event-source-demo)"
3. $ sh run.sh

After running the above scripts, The following snippet errors occurs.

```
2017-03-18 22:33:14.025  INFO 5136 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2017-03-18 22:33:14.151 ERROR 5136 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4]
    a
```

It seems like created docker images not linked to each other or was not able to establish connections.

Please let me know if you need more log details.